# Play video inside kivy canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I have put the video inside kivy canvas, first 3 sec showing image afterthat will be play video. But only show all time image only.
Any suggestion.

Thanks

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle ,Color
from kivy.core.video import Video as CoreVideo
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Mycanvas(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kw):
    super(Mycanvas,self).__init__(**kw)
    with self.canvas:
        self.bg = Rectangle(source='Flower.jpg', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.video = CoreVideo()
        self.video.bind(on_frame=self.set_bg_texture)
        self.video.filename = 'Garden.mp4'
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_vid, 3)
        self.start_vid(3)

    def start_vid(self, dt):
        self.video.play()

    def set_bg_texture(self, *args):
        self.bg.texture = self.video.texture

class mainapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Mycanvas()


mainapp().run()
```

Comment: Your code seems to mostly work for me. Perhaps Kivy can't handle your video file. Try using the `cityCC0.mpg` in the `examples/widgets` directory of the Kivy download.

Comment: thank you for responding , I have tried above mentioned file(cityCC0.mpg) , but didn't work always showed only 'flower.jpg' image

Comment: Are you getting an error message like: `[ERROR  ] [ffpyplayer  ] Garden.mp4: No such file or directory`?

Comment: 'Garden.mp4' it my video file , video present same name so error didn't come for me and shown image only.

Comment: Now it working fine. Simplely update (sudo apt update)  thanks